# Setting Gradient in a Line Object using Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

What i'm trying to do is setting a Gradient in a Line object but so far i haven't.
In other kind of objects like `Rect` and `Circle` are straight forward and there are a lots of examples.

https://jsfiddle.net/o1ezLcjv/1/

Snippet

```
                    var coords = [];
                    coords.push(15);
                    coords.push(17);
                    coords.push(150);
                    coords.push(190);

                    var line = new fabric.Line(coords, {
                        fill : 'red',
                        stroke : 'red',
                        strokeWidth : 5,
                        selectable : true
                    });

                    line.setGradient('fill', {
                        x1: -line.width / 2,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: line.width / 2,
                        y2: 0,
                        colorStops: {
                            0: 'black',
                            1: 'red'
                        }
                    });

                    canvas.add(line);
                    canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change 'fill' to 'stroke' in the setGradient method.

```
                var coords = [];
                coords.push(15);
                coords.push(17);
                coords.push(150);
                coords.push(190);

                var line = new fabric.Line(coords, {
                    fill : 'red',
                    stroke : 'red',
                    strokeWidth : 5,
                    selectable : true
                });

                line.setGradient('stroke', {
                    x1: -line.width / 2,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: line.width / 2,
                    y2: 0,
                    colorStops: {
                        0: 'black',
                        1: 'red'
                    }
                });

                canvas.add(line);
                canvas.renderAll();
```